# Unexpected result from very simple statistics problem

Tags: self-study, combinatorics

I have stumbled across this problem on my mathematics book, the problem states:

A person is distributing 3 packages in a city consisting of 3 houses, each package assigned to a single house. He has lost the delivery notes, and doesn't know which package belongs to which house. What is the chance that at least a single package makes its way to the correct location if he distributes them randomly?

To solve the problem I decided to draw a simple "state machine". I assume that the order of visiting the houses doesn't change the result (am I wrong here?). The number below each package (the stars) is the house it's meant to be delivered to.

[image: An image of the different possible states]

Clearly, 4 out of the 6 final states have at least one correctly distributed package, so 2/3 is the result.

The solution stated by the book is 0.704 (it's rounded).

After puzzling for some time, I decided to code a quick simulation in C++, and the simulation (assuming the same premises as these used to build the graphic) converges to 2/3, too, so I wonder, am I interpreting the problem correctly? What method can lead to the result given in the book? I assume I'm missing a very easy and straightforward method as this book is designed for students new to statistics.

Comment: The textbook solution is a rounded representation of $1-(2/3)^3,$ giving the chance when you don't know there is a one-to-one matching of packages and houses: all you assume is that each package is addressed to one of these three houses.  Possibly all three needed to be delivered to the same location, for instance.  This shows how subtle changes in wording and interpretation can change a problem.  Thus, it is crucial that you quote the book's question *verbatim,* rather than paraphrasing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect your book contains an error, or you may have missed a detail you didn't give us.

We can represent the houses that the packages are delivered to as a *permutation on 3 elements*. For instance, the permutation $(123)$ represents the case where all packages are delivered correctly, and $(213)$ represents the case where the package to house $3$ is delivered correctly, and the other two have been switched.

Now, if your delivery person delivers packages at random, then every possible permutation is equally likely.

In this formulation, the probability that at least one package is delivered correctly is the probability that a random equiprobable permutation has at least one fixed point, i.e., at least one of the numbers is in the correct position.

Now, the total number of permutations on $n$ elements is $n!$. [The number of permutations with at least one fixed point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8650/51074) is $n!-!n$, where $!n$ gives the number of *derangements*, i.e., permutations with *no* fixed points. [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) gives information and a recursive formula for $!n$.

In our case, $n=3$, so $n!=6$, and it turns out that $!n=2$. (The two derangements on $n=3$ elements are $(312)$ and $(231)$, all other permutations have at least one fixed point.) So the probability you are looking for is

$$\frac{n!-!n}{n!} = \frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}. $$

Now, if your state machine, your simulation and this little calculation all end up with the same answer which is different from the one in your book, my conclusion is as above.

Comment: Thank you! I guess that the book must have some kind of error. I see the mathematical 
solution is very straightforward!

Comment: I found the book's solutions, and they reach that result by first calculating the probability of none arriving, which is calculated as $(\frac{2}{3})^3$. (That's incorrect unless you assume that the postman can give more than one packet to each house, and that's not given in the problem), and then the probability of at least one arriving is $1 - (\frac{2}{3})^3 = 0.703$

Comment: Yes, that probability is wrong, because packages being misdelivered is not independent: the probability that the second package is misdelivered is different if the first one was correctly delivered or not. Specifically, if the first package was delivered correctly, then the second package is misdelivered with $p=\frac{1}{2}$ (because we have two packages and two houses left, and one of the packages should go to one of the houses.) ...

Comment: ... Conversely, if the first package was wrongly delivered, then with $p=\frac{1}{2}$ it was the package intended for house #2, so the probability for the second delivery to be correct is zero, and with $p=\frac{1}{2}$, it was the one intended for house #3, so we still have a chance of $p=\frac{1}{2}$ to deliver the second one correctly. Thus, in this case, the probabilty for a misdelivery to the second house is $\frac{3}{4}$. ...

Comment: ... I hope the rest of the book is better.

Comment: The function analysis and geometry lessons are way better, but I'm going to use another source for statistics. I guess that this has to do with how the curriculum is designed here in Spain, statistics get really little time and are usually skipped!

Answer (score 6):

This is the "classical matching problem" (also called the "problem of coincidences") and its solution is given by the classical matching distribution.  You can read about this problem/distribution and a useful extension of the problem in [O'Neill (2023)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11009-023-10067-6).  If we let $n$ be the number of houses in your problem and $K_n$ be the number of matches (i.e., packages that go to the correct house) then we have:

$$\mathbb{P}(K_n = k) = \text{Match}(k|n)
= \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}.$$

Probabilities from the matching distribution can be computed in `R` using the `dmatching` function in the `stat.extend` package.  The probability of gettting at least a single match (i.e., at least a single package to the correct house) is:

$$\mathbb{P}(K_n > 0) = 1-\mathbb{P}(K_n = 0) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!},$$

and with $n=3$ houses we obtain the probability:

$$\mathbb{P}(K_3 > 0) = \frac{2}{3}.$$

As we take $n \rightarrow \infty$ the classical matching distribution convergences to a Poisson distribution with unit rate, so you get the limiting value:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(K_n > 0) = 1-\frac{1}{e} \approx 0.6321206.$$